# An error message in a batch file (using xcopy) about a directory not used in the file

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

At work, I must use the following script to copy `C:\wincom4\liste.cdt` (a file using a custom `cdt` extension) in `H:\Sauvegarde\`:

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\wincom4\liste.cdt" goto next
goto end

:next

set filen=liste

set wcontrol=%time:~0,1%
set wcontrol=A%wcontrol%B


if A1B==%wcontrol% goto OK2
if A2B==%wcontrol% goto OK2

set Xime=%time:~6,2%
goto FIN2

:OK2
set Xime=%time:~6,2%

:FIN2
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do set XDate=%%c-%%b-%%a
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%a in ('time /t') do set XTime=%%ah%%bm%%c

if exist "H:\Sauvegarde\liste.txt" echo sauvegarde h existe
if exist "H:\Sauvegarde\liste.txt" del "H:\Sauvegarde\liste.txt"

echo "xcopy before"
xcopy "c:\wincom4\%filen%.cdt" "H:\Sauvegarde\" /s /e /y /v /h /q /c
echo "xcopy after"

set xdat=%XDate%
set xdate=%XDate% %XTime%%Xime%

ren "H:\Sauvegarde\%filen%.cdt" "cdt - %xdate%.txt"

if exist "H:\Sauvegarde\%filen%.txt" del "H:\Sauvegarde\%filen%.txt"

xcopy "C:\wincom4\%filen%.cdt" "H:\Sauvegarde\" /s /e /y /v /h /q /c

ren "H:\Sauvegarde\%filen%.cdt" "%filen%.txt"

if exist "C:\wincom4\cdtcheck.txt" del "C:\wincom4\cdtcheck.txt"
echo Save terminated
pause
:end
```

When I run the script, I get the following message:

```
sauvegarde h existe
"xcopy before"
Accès refusé
Impossible de créer le répertoire - H:\Sauvegarde\0 - CDT
1 fichier(s) copié(s)
"xcopy after"
Accès refusé
Impossible de créer le répertoire - H:\Sauvegarde\0 - CDT
1 fichier(s) copié(s)
Save terminated.
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

I don't understand this message because:

1. The script doesn't ask for the creation of such a directory.
2. This directory already exists.

Comment: Please show us the complete output (including "xcopy before" and "xcopy after".  Also please remove everything that is not pertinent to the question.

Comment: I will post the complete output, but it's written in French:

Comment: It does not matter.  If the output says "sauvegarde h existe" I know that the statement "echo sauvegarde h existe" executed even if I don't understand the meaning of "sauvegarde h existe".

Comment: For just a single file shouldn't you use copy instead of xcopy? It was always my understanding that xcopy was for copying the contents of one directory to another.

Comment: @Timothy I must chech the flags are correct befor trying.

Comment: I believe that the `\` at the end of the destination directory name requests it be created. Normally, if it already exists then there would be no error message, so I suspect that the permissions applied to the destination directory generate the error message because the current user has not got creation rights for the directory **but** does have creation rights for files within the directory. (Too complex for me - I just turn all permissions off, and no end or problems that others have disappear for me...)

Comment: Why `/s /e` flags copying the only file? Both mean _Copy folders and subfolders_ and `/e` means _... including Empty folders_. Why `/h` flag? The file is hidden and/or system?

Comment: @Magoo I must check, but I have creation rights for the directory.

Comment: @JosefZ The file is neither hidden nor system.